# Why does THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN cause my code to run 20x slower than THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST?

Tags: c++, performance, winapi

So I won't bore you with why, but my application can optionally perform some integrity checking on very large files (Up to 50gb) using CRC.  Because I don't want to kill user's machines if they turn this option on I set the IoPriorityHintVeryLow hint on the handle and also was setting the thread priority to THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN using [this API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277(v=vs.85).aspx).

The time consuming part of my code looks like this:

```
//
// Read one block of the changed data at a time, checking each CRC
//
DWORD blockNum = 0;
vector<BYTE> changeBuffer(DIRTY_BLOCK_SIZE);
outputDirtyBlockMap.reserve(crcList.size() / 8);
while (::ReadFile(hChangedFile, changeBuffer.data(), DIRTY_BLOCK_SIZE, &bytesRead, NULL) && bytesRead > 0)
{
    // Check for cancellation every 500 blocks, doing it every time reduces CPU performance by 50% since WaitForSingleObject is quite expensive
    if ((blockNum % 500 == 0) && IsCancelEventSignalled(hCancel))
    {
        RETURN_TRACED(ERROR_CANCELLED);
    }

    // Increase the size of the dirty block map?
    ULONG mapByte = blockNum / 8;
    if (mapByte == outputDirtyBlockMap.size())
    {
        outputDirtyBlockMap.resize(mapByte + 1);
    }

    DWORD mapBitNum = blockNum & 0x7L;
    UCHAR mapBit = 1 << (7 - mapBitNum);
    if (driverDirtyBlockMap.size() > mapByte && (driverDirtyBlockMap[mapByte] & mapBit))
    {
        //
        // The bit is already set in the drivers block map, we don't have to bother generating comparing CRCs for this block
        //
        outputDirtyBlockMap[mapByte] |= mapBit;
    }
    else
    {
        // Validate that the CRC hasn't changed, if it has, mark it as such in the dirty block map
        DWORD newCrc = CRC::Crc32(changeBuffer.data(), changeBuffer.size());
        if ((blockNum >= crcList.size() || newCrc != crcList[blockNum]))
        {
            OPTIONAL_DEBUG(DEBUG_DIRTY_BLOCK_MAP & DEBUG_VERBOSE, "Detected change at block [%u], CRC [new 0x%x != old 0x%x]", blockNum, newCrc, blockNum < crcList.size() ? crcList[blockNum] : 0x0);

            // The CRC is changed or the file has grown, mark it as such in the dirty block map
            outputDirtyBlockMap[mapByte] |= mapBit;
        }
    }

    ++blockNum;
}
```

When I was profiling this code I was very surprised to find that when this loop runs in THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN it takes 74 seconds to run over a 500Mb file.  When running with THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST it takes 2.7 seconds to run over a 500Mb file.  (I've tested this around 8 times now and that was the average)

In both cases the machine I was testing on was idle other than running this loop.  So question:

Why does THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN make this take so long?  I'd have thought that if the machine isn't doing anything else, it should still run as quick as with any other priority because it doesn't need to be prioritized?

Is there something I should know about this priority that I haven't been able to figure out from the docs?

Answer (score 5):

Setting background mode has the following effects:

- Sets I/O priority to Very Low
- Sets Memory Priority to 1
- Sets Absolute Thread Priority to 4

While setting the relative thread priority to LOWEST has the following effect:

- Sets Relative Thread Priority to -2 (i.e.: Absolute 6, assuming Normal Process Priority Class)

So, in general, especially if you're I/O bound (but even in cases of being CPU bound), you would definitely expect a thread at priority 4, running with Very Low I/O priority and Background Memory Priority (1) to perform a lot more poorly than a thread with Foreground Memory Priority (5) + Normal I/O Priority at priority 6...

Comment: That's interesting, can you let me know where you got this info from?  IIRC it wasn't in the original documentation.

Comment: I believe/hope we documented this in the Windows Internals book (in the scheduling chapter). I don't have a PDF version of it handy. The original information either came from reverse engineering or talking to the kernel team. You can use Process Hacker or Process Explorer to investigate your thread after calling the API, and you should see proof of these claims :)

Comment: "*we* documented this in the Windows Internals"  -  Would Alex be short for Alex Ionescu?

Answer (score 2):

That THREAD_MODE_* is different from THREAD_PRIORITY_* is maybe not that surprising?

I don't know if the exact differences are documented anywhere but it would not surprise me if background mode tries to run everything on a single core if the CPU supports core parking and at a lower frequency.

The SetThreadPriority documentation also hints to some changes to any I/O the thread performs:

> The THREAD_PRIORITY_* values affect the CPU scheduling priority of the thread. For threads that perform background work such as file I/O, network I/O, or data processing, it is not sufficient to adjust the CPU scheduling priority; even an idle CPU priority thread can easily interfere with system responsiveness when it uses the disk and memory. Threads that perform background work should use the THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN and THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_END values to adjust their resource scheduling priorities; threads that interact with the user should not use THREAD_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN.

Have you tried to measure to see if the performance loss is in `ReadFile` or the CRC calculation?

Comment: Yes I did wonder if it was a difference in I/O prioritisation and you're right that "hint" is the word, the docs are really ambiguous.  I will do as you suggest and replace the CRC with a dummy function that just returns zero and see if it still performs with the same characteristics.  What's interesting is that I'm already explicitly using low priority I/O so if this does affect I/O it'd be an additional effect.

Comment: Right, so as a follow up.  It's the ReadFile which is being affected by the thread mode rather than the CRC.  Interesting, that's quite a profound affect on I/O.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, there is a difference between

- thread scheduling priority
- thread I/O priority

Nowhere is this difference more noticable than **Resource Monitor**, where you can see some *"background"* I/O operations take 500 ms:

[image]

When it might normally take 7 ms.

SysMain (*nee* SuperFetch) does everything at **Background** I/O priority. That's why your hard drive can be churning without SuperFetch affecting the machine.